# Google account recovery when hacker has added their phone

Tags: google-account, account-management, account-recovery

About 15 minutes ago someone managed to log in to my gmail account, and then added their phone number. I tried to follow the [suggested steps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6294825) but the problem is when it gets to the recovery part google says "we will send an alert to this phone number to verify your identity". That's not my phone number though, actually I never put a phone number on the account. I do have a recovery email set (and have had it since the day I created the account) but there doesn't seem to be any way to actually use it.

Is there any possible way to recover my account now that the hacker has put their phone on it?

EDIT: there is an old question that is similar, however the answers are out of date and no longer work. The link it tells you to click is no longer on the page. These are actually the same steps I tried originally (link above) and didn't work.

Comment: see the linked question - last section "I have no access to my recovery email, phone, or any other option"

Comment: @SathyajithBhat It looks like google's system has changed and the answer is outdated (try it yourself, the link it tells you to click isn't there anymore). How can I request an answer that works in 2021?

Comment: @Sathyajith Bhat help, how can I get an answer that works in the current system?

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you should have to contact Google support. If you have not a Google One subscription then AFAIK only way is by making a post on the [Google Accounts Help Community](https://support.google.com/accounts/community) and cross you fingers for a Product Expert to guide through the most current account recovery process for exception cases.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried the Google account help community but got no replies. I don't want to pay for Google one just to ask for recovery. Are there no other options? For example my recovery email is still attached, surely that can be used for recovering my account? :/